# In mysql combine multiple rows in one column? when having same ID with different value

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a query in which getting 2 record of same id but different groups(column) value.
here is the query:

```
SELECT rule.id, rule.rule_name,group_rule.groupName
  FROM rule LEFT JOIN rule_groups ON rule.id=rule_groups.rule_id
  LEFT JOIN group_rule ON   rule_groups.group_rule_id=group_rule.id
```

result:
---------------------------------

```
|id     |rule_name   | groupName
|1      |A           | app
|1      |A           |jaz
```

now want to combine these two rows in one record.
how to modify query to get expected result.

expected:

```
|id     |rule_name   | groupName
|1      |A           | app, jaz
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `group_concat()`:

```
select r.id, r.rule_name, group_concat(gr.groupName separator ', ')
from rule r left join
     rule_groups rg
     on r.id = rg.rule_id left join
     group_rule gr
     on rg.group_rule_id = gr.id
group by r.id, r.rule_name;
```

Note that I also introduced table aliases so the query is easier to write and read.

Comment: Agreed, but I don't think the group by needs both the id and the rule_name since `id` seems to be the primary key. But behavior for duplicate rule_name isn't specified

Comment: @JensV . . . I consider it a best practice to list all the unaggregated columns in the `group by`, especially for people learning SQL.